# Usar expresiones regulares en busquedas Linq en vb.net

Tags: vb.net, regex, linq

Suelo utilizar Linq habitualmente para hacer búsquedas y agrupaciones en colecciones de objectos, pero me encuentro con un caso nuevo para mi.

Tengo una lista de objetos, y quiero seleccionar aquellos cuya propiedad Nombre coincide con un patrón. Por ejemplo el texto "SAS" seguido de 1 a 4 digitos (SAS1, SAS23, SAS999, etc)

Creo que podría hacerlo combinando Linq con expresiones regulares, pero no soy capaz de conseguirlo.

Alguna idea?

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Y hasta ahora que has hecho? Qué es lo que no puedes conseguir exáctamente? Agrega el código que tengas en la pregunta, y alguien podrá ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este ejemplo es muy básico, el truco está aquí:

```
regex.Match(resultado.X).Length>0
```

esto representa que se encontró dentro la propiedad al menos una coincidencia, en este de [A-Z]+

```
Imports System
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
                
Public Module Module1
    
    Public class ClaseEjemplo
        
        Public Sub ClaseEjemplo(x as String, y as String)
            X = x
            Y = y
        End Sub
        
        Public X as String
        
        Public Y as String
        
    End class
    
    Public Sub Main()
        
        Dim listaOriginal as new List(of ClaseEjemplo)
            Dim item as New ClaseEjemplo
            item.X = "ASD"
            item.Y = "123"

            Dim item2 as New ClaseEjemplo
            item2.X = "QWE"
            item2.Y = "321"

        listaOriginal.Add(item)
        listaOriginal.Add(item2)
        
        listaOriginal.Add(item)
        listaOriginal.Add(item2)
        
        listaOriginal.Add(item)
        listaOriginal.Add(item2)
        
        Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("[A-Z]+")
        
        Dim resultados = From resultado In listaOriginal Where regex.Match(resultado.X).Length>0
        
        For Each resultado In resultados
            Console.WriteLine(resultado.X + "-" + resultado.Y)
        Next
        
    End Sub
    
End Module
```

Comment: ¡¡¡Muchas gracias!!!
En mi caso,  la expresión regular usada fue:

Dim pRegex As Regex = New Regex("^SAS[0-999]")

Saludos!